# Como acceder a un método de un form desde un usercontrol ubicado en ese form

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

Tengo una aplicación en vb.net hecha con visual studio 2010 en la que tengo un formulario principal. En el formulario tengo un panel donde abro una instancia de usercontrols. Pues bien, necesito acceder desde uno de esos usercontrols a un método que está en el formulario padre, y no se como hacerlo.

¿Me podríais echar una mano? 
¡Muchísimas gracias de antemano!

Edito con las partes del código importantes:

Parte del formulario que hace la conexión con el cliente:

```
Public Sub StartClient(ByVal ip As String, ByVal host As String)

    Try
        Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipAddress.Parse(ip)
        Dim remoteEP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Integer.Parse(host))

        Ipport.Connect(ip, host)
        Ipport.EOL = vbLf
        BunifuImageButton1.Image = My.Resources.bombilla
        lbIp.Text = "IP: " & ip
        lbPort.Text = "Puerto: " & host
    Catch ex As Exception
        BunifuImageButton1.Image = My.Resources.bombillamal2
        lbIp.Text = "NO CONECTADO"
        lbPort.Text = ""
    End Try
End Sub
```

Parte del formulario donde llamo al usercontrol y lo meto en el panel:

```
Private Sub BunifuTileButton2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BunifuTileButton2.Click
    panelPrincipal.Controls.Clear()
    panelPrincipal.Controls.Add(gestionManual)


End Sub
```

Y en el usercontrol tengo un botón que es el que en principio se encargaría de coger la ip y puerto y pasárselos al método del formulario para hacer la conexión.

Si necesitáis cualquier cosa más decidme y copio el código que sea.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Suena a que algo no está bien en tu diseño. Un user control no debería tener esta clase de dependencia a su formulario padre. Si el user control tiene alguna dependencia externa, debería ser la responsabilidad del formulario de suministrar lo que el user control necesita, no el contrario. Si aun así piensas que necesitas hacer lo que pides, por favor agrega más detalles y tu código.

Comment: Igual no he explicado suficiente de mi problema. En el formulario principal tengo un picturebox y dos labels que indican si la conexión funciona bien o no (una que se hace por defecto al cargar el formulario). La cosa es que el usercontrol que abro es para realizar una conexión manual, y el metodo de la conexión está en el formulario. No se si me he explicado mejor o he empeorado todo..

Comment: Creo que voy entendiendo. Pero para tenerlo bien claro, por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye las porciones relevantes del formulario y user control que apoyan tu explicación.

Comment: el comentario lo explica mejor. sin embargo la solucion no es acceder al form contenedor. si no que el user control dispare algun evento cuando de llena y ese evento sea agarrado por el form, quien toma los parametros y realiza la conexion. Igual que quien se encargue de conectar sea el form y no una clase particular tambien es raro.

Comment: Ya he editado con trozos del código, a ver si así podéis ayudarme algo mejor. La opción de los eventos la probaría, pero lo cierto es que no tengo ni idea de como crearlos, donde ni nada... lo he intentado mirando la documentación pero no he conseguido hacerlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de hacer esto es tal como lo describe @gbianchi en su comentario. O sea definiendo un evento en tu user control al que el formulario se suscribe. Cuando se le hace clic al botón de tu user control, disparas el evento pasándole los valores de `IP` y `puerto`, y el formulario, al detectar el evento, recibe los valores y ejecuta el código deseado.

Ejemplo de cómo definir el evento en tu user control:

```
Public Class GestionManualUserControl
   ' Este es el evento, puedes escoger asignarle otro nombre.
   Public Event ButtonClick(ip As String, port As String)

   Private Sub boton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles boton.Click
      ' aquí disparas el evento cuando se le hace click al botón.
      ' Aprovechas para pasar los valores para IP y puerto.
      RaiseEvent ButtonClick(txtIp.Text, txtPort.Text)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Luego, en tu formulario, tan solo necesitas agregar un método que maneje el evento definido en tu user control. En este caso, se llama `ButtonClick`, pero el nombre lo puedes escoger tu cuando defines el evento en tu user control:

```
Private Sub gestionManual_ButtonClick(ip As String, port As String) Handles gestionManual.ButtonClick
   StartClient(ip, port)
End Sub
```

Comment: Lo tengo hecho así, pero me tira un error:

"La cláusula Handles requiere una variable WithEvents definida en el tipo contenedor o en uno de sus tipos base."

Qué puedo hacer para solucionar eso?
Y muchísimas gracias a todos por la ayuda!!

Comment: Solucionado, al final solo he tenido que eliminar el "Handles gestionManual.ButtonClick" de:
Private Sub gestionManual_ButtonClick(ip As String, port As String) Handles gestionManual.ButtonClick